# Create a pin code. No navigation when re-entering a pin

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a screen with creating a pin code to enter the application. But unfortunately my code doesn't work.

I'm trying to implement this through local storage. Here's the logic - as soon as the user goes to the create screen, I check if there is a pin code in the local storage.
Here is the function -

```
Future<int?> sharedPrefsGet() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(await prefs.getInt('pinCode'));
    return await prefs.getInt('pinCode');
  }

  late final Future<int?> future = sharedPrefsGet();


 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sharedPrefsGet();
  }
```

Further, when entering the pin code, I check if there is a pin code and what will happen -

```
onCompleted: (value) async {
                      pinCode = int parse(value);
                      sharedPrefsSet(pinCode);
                      if(sharedPrefsGet() == value) {
                        context.go('/home');
                      } else {
                        context.go('/createPinCode');
                      }
                      context.go('/createPinCode');
                    },
```

and of course, there I try to save the pin code to the local storage. Here is the function -

```
var pinCode;


   sharedPrefsSet(int pin) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.setInt('pinCode', pin);
   }
```

but my code doesn't work, I don't get any errors.

The user enters the password, this screen opens again, he enters the code again, but navigation to the home page no longer occurs. Why?

full code -

```
class CreatePinCode extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreatePinCodeState createState() => _CreatePinCodeState();
}

class _CreatePinCodeState extends State<CreatePinCode> {

  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  var pinCode;


   sharedPrefsSet(int pin) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await prefs.setInt('pinCode', pin);
   }

  Future<int?> sharedPrefsGet() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(await prefs.getInt('pinCode'));
    return await prefs.getInt('pinCode');
  }

  late final Future<int?> future = sharedPrefsGet();



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    sharedPrefsGet();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ConfigColor.background,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          FutureBuilder(
              future: future,
              builder: (context, snapshot) =>
              snapshot.hasData? Text('123123123123123') : Text('ababababab')
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 70,
              child: Center(
                  child: PinCodeTextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    obscuringWidget: Container(
                      width: 15,
                      height: 15,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: ConfigColor.green,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle
                      ),
                    ),
                    appContext: context,
                    length: 4,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      print(value);
                    },
                    pinTheme: PinTheme(
                      shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      fieldHeight: 15,
                      fieldWidth: 15,
                      activeColor: ConfigColor.green,
                      inactiveColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                      disabledColor:  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                    ),
                    onCompleted: (values) async {
                      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                      final pinCod = await prefs.setInt('pinCod', int.parse(values));

                      if(!pinCod) {// either true or false
                        if(pinCod == int.parse(values)) {
                          log('Все хорошо');
                        } else {
                          log('Код не совпадает!');
                        }
                      }
                      pinCode = int.parse(values);
                      final int? value =  await sharedPrefsGet() ;
                      if(value== null) {
                        context.go('/createPinCode');
                      } else if (value == pinCode){
                        await sharedPrefsSet(pinCode);
                        context.go('/home');
                      } else {

                      }
                    },
                  )
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // implement the custom NumPad
          NumPad(
            buttonSize: 65,
            buttonColor: ConfigColor.background,
            iconColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            controller: _controller,
            delete: () {
              _controller.text = _controller.text
                  .substring(0, _controller.text.length - 1);
            },
            // do something with the input numbers
            onSubmit: () {

              debugPrint('Your code: ${_controller.text}');
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                    content: Text(
                      "You code is ${_controller.text}",
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                    ),
                  ));
            },
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would better add return type on `sharedPrefsGet` while it is returning a future.

```dart
 Future<int> sharedPrefsGet() async {
```

Using Future builder to get data.

```dart
   sharedPrefsSet(int pin) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setInt('pinCode', pin);
   }

  Future<int?> sharedPrefsGet() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(await prefs.getInt('pinCode'));
    return await prefs.getInt('pinCode');
  }


  late final Future<int?> future = sharedPrefsGet();
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) =>  
        snapshot.hasData? 
          Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
             !snapshot.hasData ? Text('ababababab') : Text('123123123'),

  .........
```

And use await to get data

```dart
onCompleted: (value) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final pinCod = await prefs.setInt('pinCod', int.parse(value));
  
  if(!pinCod) {// either true or false
    if(pinCod == int.parse(value)) {
      log('Все хорошо');
    } else {
      log('Код не совпадает!');
    }
  }
  pinCode = int.parse(value);
final int? value =  await sharedPrefsGet() ;
  if(value== null) {
      
  } else if (value== youValue){
    await sharedPrefsSet(pinCode);
    
  } else {
    
  }
},
```

Comment: Sorry, navigation to the home screen did not work

Comment: Can you use FutureBuilder instead of initState

Comment: Yes. But where exactly do I need to use it?

Comment: Can you also put `await  sharedPrefsSet(pinCode);`

Comment: I installed it but still the problem is not solved

Comment: do you get value on `onCompleted`'s `sharedPrefsSet`? Also remove the bottom `context.go('/createPinCode');`

Comment: yep. I'm get value

Comment: try update part, btw `onCompleted` is the issue ?

Comment: I looked under debug. When I enter the code for the second time, for some reason it does not fall into the first if
I didn't quite understand your last remark

Comment: btw dont rebuild the app, it will get reinstall and there will be no value, try testing with building app, instead of debug mode

Comment: I tried so many times. But, unfortunately, navigation does not work :(

Comment: Can you provide two sample widget

Comment: which ones? Where onCompleted?

Comment: full from scaffold,

Comment: should I upload everything here? I can upload to a third party service and give you a link. How is it better?

Comment: check pls, i'm adeed full code

Comment: ` prefs.setInt` doesnt return nullable data, you can get bool there

Comment: Undefined name 'youValue'. (Documentation)

Comment: that will be the  value you like to compare

Comment: I always fall into this condition. -if(value==null) {
                         context.go('/createPinCode');
                         log('first if');
                       }
Also, I changed the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

problem is here :

```
sharedPrefsGet() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(await prefs.getInt('pinCode'));
    return await prefs.getInt('pinCode');
  }
```

when you are doing this : `prefs.getInt('pinCode')`

Instead of this Try to do this :

```
sharedPrefsGet() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    print(await prefs.getInt('pinCode') ?? -1);
    return await prefs.getInt('pinCode') ?? -1; //here -1 means not given pin 
  }
```

now add your code for this logic

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Here's what I got in the console - `I/flutter ( 3502): -1
I/flutter ( 3502): -1`
Entered the code for the first time received -
`I/flutter ( 3502): -1`
I enter the second time and get -
`I/flutter ( 3502): -1`

Comment: then in the 2nd time when you are trying to store . 1st parse it to INT then store it . i think type is not matching so its not storing

Comment: `if(await sharedPrefsGet() == int.parse(value)) {`
I did this but it doesn't work

Comment: ok i got it . add some delay ! . when you call getStoredValue() then it takes time to come . you need add delay . your problem will be solved